# Replace into equivalent for postgresql and then autoincrementing an int

Tags: sql, postgresql, merge, upsert

Okay no seriously, if a PostgreSQL guru can help out I'm just getting started.

Basically what I want is a simple table like such:

```
CREATE TABLE schema.searches
(
  search_id serial NOT NULL,
  search_query character varying(255),
  search_count integer DEFAULT 1,
  CONSTRAINT pkey_search_id PRIMARY KEY (search_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

I need something like `REPLACE INTO` for MySQL. I don't know if I have to write my own procedure or something?

Basically:

- check if the query already exists
- if so, just add 1 to the count
- it not, add it to the db

I can do this in my php code but I'd rather all that be done in postgres C engine

Comment: What you're looking for is referred to as either an "upsert" or "merge"

Comment: This is not a duplicate per se. `REPLACE INTO` is delete-then-insert, which has different implications than upsert.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a unique constraint first.

```
ALTER TABLE schema.searches ADD UNIQUE (search_query);
```

The insert/replace command looks like this.

```
INSERT INTO schema.searches(search_query) VALUES ('a search query')
ON CONFLICT (search_query)
DO UPDATE SET search_count = schema.searches.search_count + 1;
```